# How to import a child component correctly into an lazy loaded IonicPage?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have this problem where my child component throws "is not a known element:" error.

this is my module component **Bubble-list.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BubbleListComponent } from './bubble-list.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        BubbleListComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(BubbleListComponent),
    ],
    exports: [
        BubbleListComponent
    ]
})
export class BubbleListComponentModule { }
```

**bubble-list.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'bubble-list',
  templateUrl: 'bubble-list.html'
})
export class BubbleListComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    this.text = 'Hello Hello BubbleListComponent Component ';
    console.log(this.text);
  }

}
```

my Parent Module

```
import { BubbleListComponent } from './components/bubble-list/bubble-list.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyMainPage } from './my-editor';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyMainPage
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(MyMainPage),
        BubbleListComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        MyMainPage
    ],
    providers: [

    ]
})
export class MyMainPageModule { }
```

And in my HTML

```
<div
    <bubble-list></bubble-list>
</div>
```

If I declare them in `app.module`'s `@NgModule()` declarations it works but I want to keep all the child components inside my Parent component. because they are not needed in other places. I am missing something?

The error is:

```
'bubble-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'bubble-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'bubble-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here the complete Error:

```
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'bubble-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'bubble-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'bubble-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (""><br><br><br><br>newItem: {{annotationsProvider.bubbleInEdition.isNewItem}}<br><br><br></div>

    [ERROR ->]<bubble-list></bubble-list>
</ion-menu>

"): ng:///AppModule/myParentPage.html@14:4 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
'bubble-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'bubble-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'bubble-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (""><br><br><br><br>newItem: {{annotationsProvider.bubbleInEdition.isNewItem}}<br><br><br></div>

    [ERROR ->]<bubble-list></bubble-list>
</ion-menu>

"): ng:///AppModule/myParentPage.html@14:4
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:91164:34)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:101655:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115406:39)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115330:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115330:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115215:19)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8971)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4140)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13731 Error: Template parse errors:
'bubble-list' is not a known element:
1. If 'bubble-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'bubble-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (""><br><br><br><br>newItem: {{annotationsProvider.bubbleInEdition.isNewItem}}<br><br><br></div>

    [ERROR ->]<bubble-list></bubble-list>
</ion-menu>

"): ng:///AppModule/myParentPage.html@14:4
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:91164:34)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:101655:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115406:39)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115330:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115330:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:115215:19)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:8971)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4140)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:13731
```

Data structure

```
/src
   /pages
      /my-parent-page
            myparent.module   && myparent.component
          /components
              /bubble-editor/
                  bubble.module  && bubble.component
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**: Keep lazyload and import child Page to parent Module.

```
import { BubbleListComponent } from './components/bubble-list/bubble-list.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyMainPage } from './my-editor';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyMainPage,
        BubbleListComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(MyMainPage)        
    ],
    exports: [
        MyMainPage
    ],
    providers: [

    ]
})
```

It works fine when debug but when you build with `--prod`, it will throw an error.
**Method 2**: Remove lazy load and do the same as method 1. 
 
Remove `@IonicPage` in `bubble.component` and delete `bubble.module`. After that do the same like method 1. It works fine in all case. `bubble.component` will load at the same time `MyMainPage` load.
**Method 3**: Keep lazy load and import child Module to parent Module.

```
import { BubbleListComponentModule } from './components/bubble-list/bubble-list.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyMainPage } from './my-editor';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyMainPage
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(MyMainPage),
        BubbleListComponentModule        
    ],
    exports: [
        MyMainPage
    ],
    providers: [

    ]
})
```

I just test this method in `ionic serve` and it works fine. Please test it in other case :-)

Comment: The third method looks like the answer I got before (and it is what I want to achieve) but it throwed me the same error. Do I need to declare/import/export  something else in other files besides what I have to do in the parent module? (I am not in my pc atm)

Comment: You do not need to do something else. That is all. I think you should use the second method .It  works well in all case

Answer (score 0):

import `BubbleListComponentModule` instead of `BubbleListComponent` in parent module.

parent Module

```
import { BubbleListComponentModule } from './components/bubble-list/bubble-list.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyMainPage } from './my-editor';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyMainPage
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(MyMainPage),
        BubbleListComponentModule 
    ],
    exports: [
        MyMainPage
    ],
    providers: [

    ]
})
export class MyMainPageModule { }
```

> Error : 1. If 'bubble-list' is an Angular component, then verify that
>   it is part of this module.

Says that component has to be packaged inside the module to be distributed, which you have done correct. And then import the module instead of component.

Comment: I get the same error, I forgot to say that my Page is lazy loaded (I do not know if that is important)

Comment: Same error, I also tried importing `BubbleListComponent` and `BubbleListComponentModule` with no luck.

Comment: Just confirming. In your component you have the right `selector : 'bubble-list'` is it?

Comment: Yes, as I said it works when I put import in app.module declarations

Comment: Ok. Can you show the directory structure like how app, parent and Bubble-list modules are related? And can you show the full `error` that you are getting. You claim that child component throws the error, but I bet its from the other source.

Comment: Yes, I had add it to the question.